# Software/Website to benchmark / test LCD Monitors

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, display, benchmarking

I'm looking for software (or a website) capable of performing LCD tests to check artifacts on LCD screens, dead pixels, benchmark the phase/clock, angle vision, response time, contrast, calibration, etc.

I mean for human eye feedback. Suppose you bought a new monitor and you want to check if it is really good to your eyes. So it would e.g. need to show test patterns.

OS: Windows or Linux
Price: Free

Comment: @Azevedo DisplayMate Multimedia Edition ($495 direct) is software only - there are lots of charged for options out there.

Answer (score 1):

[Displaymate](http://www.displaymate.com/) often comes up regard those kinds of things on benchmarking websites.
It is not free however ($69/$89).

Answer (score 1):

All of the photography forums seem to agree that while you can get a monitor set-up for colour by eye with reference images such as http://www.monitorsetup.com/ *which does assume that you have a set of photographic colour reference cards* you will only get an accurate colour, *or color depending where you are in the world,* profile by using a hardware solution such as [DataColor Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/products/) *currently ranging from €109.00 to 259€ for the monitor calibration tools*.

Checking for Dead & Hot Pixels is usually a matter of looking **carefully** at the screen while displaying, full screen, **pure** Black, White, Red, Green & Blue pages/images but again there are hardware tools used but magazines and manufacturers that consist of a very expensive camera *which you have to know has no dead/hot sensors and a resolution at least twice that of your screen*.

Checking Viewing angle is easily done by moving round the screen but for accurate results you would need hardware costing thousands.

For checking Geometry I suggest using images from a site such as [monitorsetup](http://www.monitorsetup.com/) and a straight edge such as a ruler.